# Posição de «sempre»​

Tags: gramática, sintaxe

Vejo com frequência os falantes não nativos terem dificuldades com a posição de «sempre». Nomeadamente, em português europeu, a seguinte frase não é possível (*sempre* tem de estar em posição pós-verbal):

> *Ele sempre se recusava a falar do assunto.

Mas estas são-no, embora com significados diferentes:

> Ele recusou-se sempre a falar do assunto.
>   Ele sempre se recusou a falar do assunto.

Em português do Brasil, as regras parecem ser diferentes.

A pergunta é, então, quais são as posições possíveis de «sempre» nas duas variedades, quais são as diferenças de significado e qual a lógica por trás das regras?

Comment: I can't believe my eyes. The first sentence looks completely legitimate to me. habitual past tense verbs should be modifiable. The second sentence also looks great. The third, though, has "always" modifying a preterit past —you'd think _that_ would never be correct: "always" implies a habit or custom and pretty much directly contradicts a specific instance of anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precisamos de distinguir os dois tipos de significados de ***sempre***. Há os significados temporais:

> Continuamente: *Tenho sempre fruta em casa*;
>   Regularmente: *Ele levanta-se sempre às 7 da manhã*;
>   Em todas as ocasiões: *Ele recusava-se sempre a discutir o assunto*;
>   Repetidamente: *Ele está sempre a interromper-me*.

Mas depois há os significados alternativos, que são muito comuns em Portugal; no Brasil são igualmente comuns na literatura do século XIX, mas parecem ter rareado no XX. Nestes sentidos, *sempre* vem sempre antes do verbo:

> Apesar de dúvidas; contra as expetativas; confirma-se que; afinal:
>   ● *Ele disse que não vinha ao jantar, mas sempre veio.*
>   ● *Disseste que talvez viesses connosco à praia; sempre vens?*
>
> Realmente: *sempre és muito guloso!*
>
> Apesar de tudo o resto; pelo menos; afinal:
>   ● *Aceitei o estágio não remunerado; sempre ganho alguma experiência.*
>   ● *Fui com eles à praia; sempre foi melhor que ficar sozinho em casa.*
>
> ***Sempre querer ver***, que não encontrei em dicionário nenhum. Tipicamente irónico, exprimindo ceticismo, pessimismo:
>   ● *Sempre quero ver onde é que vais comprar uma gravata a uma hora destas.*
>   ● *Ele disse que fazia o jantar; sempre quero ver o que é que dali sai.*

No sentido temporal, é verdade que frases do tipo «ele sempre se recusava a discutir o assunto» soam estranhas a ouvidos portugueses, mas parecem ser comuns no Brasil. Há no entanto certo tipo de construções em que o *sempre* temporal vem, mesmo em Portugal, sem problemas antes do verbo, nomeadamente quando *sempre* vem adverbiado por *nem* ou *quase*, ou em orações iniciados por pronomes relativos, como, porque, etc.:

> Ele nem sempre se recusava a discutir o assunto
>
> Ele quase sempre se recusava a discutir o assunto.
>
> Como ele sempre se recusava a discutir o assunto, nós nem sequer tentávamos.
>
> Não tocávamos no assunto, porque ele sempre se recusava a discuti-lo.
>
> Era esse o assunto que ele sempre se recusava a discutir.
>
> Era esse o assunto cujos pormenores ele sempre recusava discutir.
>
> Não era a Joana, mas sim ele quem sempre se recusava a discutir o assunto.

Exceto no primeiro exemplo, pospor o *sempre* não alteraria o significado. Já o primeiro exemplo me parece diferente de «ele nem se recusava sempre a discutir os assunto».

Andei a ver neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) o padrão do uso de *sempre*. No presente e pretérito imperfeito do indicativo no Brasil do século XIX e em Portugal até hoje, o *sempre* é anteposto ao verbo praticamente só neste tipo construções ou quando tem um dos significados alternativos. Já no Brasil do século XX aparece anteposto aparentemente em todo o tipo de construções com sentido temporal, ao passo que os significados alternativos praticamente desapareceram. No pretérito perfeito, quer no Brasil quer em Portugal, o *sempre* temporal já é liberalmente usado antes do verbo, e os significados alternativos raramente aparecem. Esta raridade dos significados alternativos no pretérito perfeito em Portugal é curiosa: creio que os meus dois exemplos acima com *sempre + pretérito perfeito* são perfeitamente típicos em Portugal.

É verdade, como se pode ver na tabela abaixo) que há no Brasil relativamente a Portugal uma maior tendência a antepor o *sempre* ao verbo (o rácio (sempre + verbo)/(verbo + sempre) é sempre maior no Brasil). Predomina no entanto, nos dois países, o *sempre* posposto no presente e pretérito imperfeito do indicativo; enquanto no pretérito perfeito predomina o *sempre* anteposto.

```
                         Presente            Imperfeito           Perfeito
                    Portugal  Brasil     Portugal  Brasil     Portugal Brasil
(1) Sempre + verbo    473      600         302      305         699     963
(2) Verbo + sempre   1317     1018         680      401         458     164
(1)/(2)              0,36     0,59        0,44     0,76         1,5     5,9
Ocorrências nos 100 primeiros verbos no Corpus do Português.
```

Resta dizer que dizer que «ele sempre se recusava a falar do assunto» é impossível no português europeu é uma força de expressão. A frase soa-me estranha, mas conseguem-se encontrar em Portugal frases do mesmo tipo (isto é, que me parecem igualmente um pouco estranhas; ênfase minha):

> Corina […] tinha contínuas entrevistas com damas responsáveis que a requisitavam para os saraus de beneficência, revistinhas cantaroladas com guarda-roupa de papel e quadros-vivos ― o sonho de Jacob, a bela adormecida no bosque ― e em que Corina ***sempre era*** a princesa de gola à Médicis sorrindo sobre um leito de tapete de mesa de jantar. (Agustina Bessa Luís, *Os Incuráveis*, 1982.)
>
> Assim (..) dum' auganal', como a gente cá chama. Aquilo é por baixo; e a gente ***sempre tinha*** um espiche lá (..) no fundo daquele pote, quando ia subindo (..).. Tinha água..(Corpus de dialetos portugueses [CordialSIN PVC12](http://www.clul.ul.pt/resources/212-cordial-sin-syntax-oriented-corpus-of-portuguese-dialects))

Comment: Está bem visto que nos significados alternativos _sempre_ vem preposto (incl. no imperfeito _ah, então sempre gostavas dela!_) e que _nem_ leva consigo _sempre_ para trás do verbo. Mas o resto já não consigo acompanhar. A posição canónica com _quase_ é depois do verbo (CETEMPúblico: 4 contra 20) e as restantes frases parecem-me ser ou mais incomuns ou mesmo marginais. Parece-me ainda que há uma diferença entre as duas posições que não exploras: _sempre ouvi dizer_ parece-me diferente de _ouvi sempre dizer_ e (continua)

Comment: (provavelmente relacionado) por que alguns tempos (imperfeito, perfeito composto) não aceitam tão bem a preposição (possivelmente a questão do tempo é apenas um sintoma de qualquer outro aspeto)

Comment: Interessante também que os 4 casos de "quase" "sempre" <imperfeito do indicativo> no CETEMPúblico são todos introduzidos por "que" (uma completiva e três relativas). Isso parece de facto dar alguma aceitabilidade.

Comment: Quanto ao exemplo "Ele disse que não vinha ao jantar, mas sempre veio.", existe em pt-PT a forma negativa, muito comum na língua inglesa ?  ("He said he would come for dinner but he never showed up")

Comment: @Artefacto No Corpus também é em Portugal 23 imperfeito + *quase sempre* contra 7 imperfeito + *quase sempre*. Mas o que eu digo em relação a esta construção e às restantes é que não me soam estranhas, e o *sempre* preposto ao imperfeito e presente, para além dos significados alternativos, ocorre praticamente só em construções desse tipo. Depois há muita coisa que eu não abordo porque não cheguei a conclusão nenhuma.

Comment: @Centaurus Aí dirias «disse que vinha, mas não veio», «mas afinal não veio», «mas não chegou a vir», «mas acabou por não vir».

Comment: Encontrei aqui [um artigo relevante](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/396262cf33d8a7c1ca262b67b0c88e6f).

Comment: Eles fazem uma distinção entre _quantificação temporal universal_ (pré-verbal) e _correlação de eventos_ (pós-verbal, exigindo uma _sucessão de eventos_). Quererão com isto dizer que comparando _Arafat sempre defendeu um Estado multiétnico_ com _Arafat defendeu sempre um Estado multiétnico_, a diferença seria a mesma que entre _não houve período em que Arafat não defendesse a multietnicidade_ e _não houve ocasião em que Araf não defendesse a multietnicidade_? Parece-me plausível, mas não tenho a certeza.

Comment: @Artefacto Também me parece plausível. Fiquei com a sensação de tender a encontrar a anteposição mais em qualidades permanentes (*sempre foi muito curioso*) e a posposição mais quando há ações implícitas (*foi sempre difícil prever o passo seguinte do dr. Savimbi*). Mas parece-me apenas um tendência: também encontro *foi sempre enfermiça e triste*. Mas é verdade que o *sempre* ganha força ao ser anteposto. Estou a pensar porque é que não é anteposto no presente e imperfeito. Será por não ser necessário? Estes tempos não estão limitados no tempo: *ele é/era curioso* significa que é/era sempre.

Comment: @Artefacto Mas *foi curioso* pode ter sido apenas brevemente; logo o *sempre* faz diferença.

Comment: @Jacinto É verdade, como eles próprios dizem o _sempre_ posposto pode redundar na mesma leitura que o preposto se não foi for possível uma leitura de correlação e dependendo doutros fatores. Mas estou mais convencido de que a preposição tem escopo sobre o tempo e uma leitura de quantificação universal temporal. Repara na estranheza de «naquela altura ele sempre foi curioso». Isso poderia explicar a grande parte do imperfeito; este geralmente é usado juntamente com enquadramentos temporais incompatíveis («nessa altura, sempre se recusava...», como no corpo da pergunta).

Comment: Ou porque não há problema com o futuro simples («Sempre te amarei»), mas o há com «sempre te vou amar», que é prospetivo. Ou porque não há problema com o MQM («até aí, sempre se recusara»); com o perfeito composto («sempre se tem recusado») tenho algumas dúvidas, não me parece muito natural estendê-lo indefinidamente para o passado (como em «ele tem-se recusado desde sempre»); se pospusermos a leitura iterativa é completamente compatível com uma «sucessão de eventos».

Answer (score 3):

Em ptBR o advérbio "sempre" não parece mudar o significado da frase quando posicionado nas duas formas indicadas na pergunta.

- **"Ele sempre desejou ter um BMW"** ou **"Ele desejou sempre ter um BMW"** -  A segunda frase soa menos usual que a primeira mas tem o mesmo significado.
- **"Ela sempre se ofereceu para ajudar"** ou **"Ela se ofereceu sempre para ajudar"** - Da mesma forma, não percebo nenhuma diferença semântica entre as duas frases.

Diferentes de **"Ela se ofereceu para ajudar sempre."**, em que o significado pode ser "sempre que precisassem", "sempre que necessário", etc.

Comment: Pois, eu vejo frequenemente «sempre» em posição pré-verbal em textos brasileiros onde em Portugal se usaria em posição pós-verbal. Em Portugal, «ele desejou sempre ter um BMW» é a frase «normal», «sempre desejou» é uma posição mais marcada. Faria sentido por exemplo em: - Parece que ele agora quer um BMW. - Ele sempre quis ter um BMW. De qualquer forma, respondes apenas a parte da pergunta. E com os outros tempos verbais?

Comment: @Artefacto   Embora eu sempre recorra a norma culta ao responder, minhas respostas não seguem a gramática prescriptivista a risca.  Respondo como alguém que é um falante nativo há muitas décadas e sempre me refiro à língua viva, conforme ouço e leio habitualmente em jornais e revistas.  Em pt-BR "ela sempre procurou", "ela procurou sempre", "ela sempre procurava", "ela procurava sempre", etc, a diferença é apenas o tempo verbal. O significado muda porque o tempo verbal mudou, mas a posição pré ou pós verbo, de um modo geral, não altera o significado.

Comment: Confirmo o que o Centaurus diz. Quase sempre em pt-BR, tanto antes quanto depois do verbo, o significado continua o mesmo. Porém, em alguns casos, pode ser interpretado de duas maneiras, como por exemplo o exemplo da BMW. "Ele desejou sempre ter um BMW", também pode ser entendido que ele desejou ter uma BMW para o resto da vida dele (para sempre).

Comment: @BrunoLopes  É verdade, não havia pensado nessa possibilidade

Comment: @ANeves   soa melhor assim.